# Unable to determine entry point

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, dll, xna, entry-point

I'm developing an XNA game for Windows Phone, but when I try to build I get this error:

> Error  49  Unable to determine the entry point.
>
> Assembly ‘C:\Users\JD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Jetpack\Jetpack\Jetpack\bin\Windows Phone\Release\Jet-Bot.dll'
>
> has no visible types deriving from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.

I checked my references and they all utilize Windows Phone/Silverlight DLL's and not Windows DLL's.

I've tried deleting and re-adding all my references with no luck, and I've also started a new project and copied and pasted all of my code over, but I still get the same problem.

What could be done to try and solve this issue?

Comment: Silly question, but does Jet-Bot.dll define a visible type deriving from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game?

Comment: I would assume so, how would I go about checking that? What elements of the DLL should I be look out for?

Comment: Allow me to rephrase.  Does the _source code_ for Jet-Bot.dll--which I assume is your game's primary assembly--contain a _public class_ deriving from `Game`?